# Jquery UI Draggable clone disappearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-draggable

I am trying to use the `jquery-ui draggable` to make some element draggable.
I set the `helper` option to `clone`  the current element.
It's making the clone correctly but when I drop the clone disappears. It doesn't stay at the dragged place.

See this for Demo [Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/b76vbr0h/)

```
$('#drag').draggable({
helper: function (e, ui) {
    return $(this).clone();
}
});
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There maybe a simpler way, but through data of draggable, you can target a property that deals with this. Like this:

```
stop : function(e, ui){
         $('#drag').draggable().data()["ui-draggable"].cancelHelperRemoval = true;
    }
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n10ucrLd/

Comment: thanks for your response. There is another case with your fiddle. the newly created div are not move able. can we do anything about that.?

Comment: do you want them draggable with cloning as well? if not, you can simply apply draggable to cloning in your helper function. Like this:  return $(this).clone().draggable();

Answer (score 3):

I think there's been a lot of troubles with `helper: 'clone'`. I always got it to work, when I defined a droppable as well. E.g.:

HTML:

```
<div id="drag">Drag This</div>
<div class="container"></div>
```

JavScript:

```
$('#drag').draggable({
helper: function (e, ui) {
    return $(this).clone(true);
}
});

 $( ".container" ).droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
       ui.draggable.clone().appendTo($(this)).draggable();
    }
 });
```

Live example: http://jsbin.com/vibeqaganu/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: thanks for your response. Can you please provide another link with your code? this link seems not working.